# How to bind the values in component to fetch the values in controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a component to insert quote, but am unable to bind the value with attribute.

KYC.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" controller="KYCQuote">
    <!--Style-->
    <aura:html tag="style">
          .slds-modal__container{
        height : auto;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 70rem;
        }
        .modal-body{
        height : 500px !important;
        max-height: 500px !important;
        }       
        .customFooter{
        display: inline !important;
        }
    </aura:html> 

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="quot" type="apttus_proposal_proposal__c"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="error" type="Boolean"/>

    <aura:attribute name="oppr" type="Opportunity__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="billingAddress" type="object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="postingAddress" type="object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acv" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="storeRadioValue" type="string"/>

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default="Loading..."/>

     <aura:if isTrue="{!not(v.isModalOpen)}">    
    <div class="slds-scrollable slds-p-around_medium slds-text-heading_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
       <p style="height: 108px; word-wrap: break-word;">{!v.message}</p><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
       <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.accept}" label="Accept" />
    </div>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">

    <div class="modal-header slds-modal__header slds-size_1-of-1">
        <h4 class="title slds-text-heading_large">Quote/KYC</h4><!-- Quote/-->
    </div>


    <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest">


    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_x-small" ><!--style="max-height:400px; overflow:auto;"  -->
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="apttus_proposal_proposal__c" >
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold"><b>Proposal Information</b></div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>


            <!--Section 1-->
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">           
                  <lightning:messages />        
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!v.quot.Account__c}" required="true"/><!--value="{!v.quot.Account__c}{!v.accId}" -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="PriceList__c" required="true" value="{!v.quot.PriceList__c}"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}" required="true"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Primary_Contact__c" value="{!v.quot.Primary_Contact__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="APTS_Quote_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Selling_Country__c" required="true" value="{v.quot.Selling_Country__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Order_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Old_Owner__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Channel__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_code_Backup__c" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Xcode__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_Code_Account_Backup__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Total1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Discount_Exception__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 2-->       
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                   <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Send Back</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages />        
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="SentBack__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="SentBackReasonText__c"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sent_Back_Reason__c"/> 
                  </div>
            </div>  

            <!--Section 3-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Pricing Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages />
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Base_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account_Entity_Use_Code__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Gross_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Total_Discount_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Tax_Percentage__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Total_Discount__c"/>
                  </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Tax_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Net_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 4-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Billing &amp; Posting Address</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages/>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillContact__c" value="{!v.quot.BillContact__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="PostingContact__c" value="{!v.quot.PostingContact__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>                 
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Special_Terms__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>



            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <div><b>Please choose billing address</b></div><br/>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.billingAddress}" var="vb"> 
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <ui:inputRadio label="{!vb}" name="bc" change="{!c.onGroup}"/>
                    </div><br/>                   
                </aura:iteration>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <div><b>Please choose posting address</b></div><br/>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.postingAddress}" var="vb"> 
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <ui:inputRadio label="{!vb}" name="pc"/>          
                    </div><br/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </div>
        </div>

            <!--Section 5-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Approval Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages/>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Level_of_Approval_Done__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Level_of_Approval__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager2__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Approval_Status__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager3__c"/>
                  </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager4__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager5__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 6-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Additional Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages/>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Payment_count__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Payment_Net_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="TDS_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Validated__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Payment_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sales_Channel_1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="CreditRequest__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Re_Process_By_With_DateTime__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sent_Back_DateTime__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Re_Process_DateTime__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.createAccount}" label="Save" />

                <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.redirect}" label="Cancel" />
            </div>

        </lightning:recordEditForm>  
    </div>
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:html tag="style">
            .footer-to-be-fixed{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            .cuf-content {
                padding: 0 0rem !important;
            }
            .slds-p-around--medium {
                padding: 0rem !important;
            }       
            .slds-modal__content{
                overflow-y:hidden !important;
                height:unset !important;
                max-height:unset !important;
            }

    </aura:html>
</aura:component>
```

This is my component code.
When i use

It displays the value as {v.quot.Selling_Country__c} in ui.

UI screen:

[image: Component screen]

Can anybody please suggest how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value="{v.quot.Selling_Country__c}` is not a valid Lightning binding expression, so it is treated as a literal string. The `!` is not optional:

`value="{! v.quot.Selling_Country__c}`

Comment: typo error. thanks David. It got resolved

Answer (score 0):

> for pre-population, you should use onload method in recordEditForms.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  objectApiName="Contact"     
                                  onload="{!c.handleOnload}"
                                  onsubmit="{!c.handleOnSubmit}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.handleOnSuccess}"
                                  onerror="{!c.handleOnError}"
                                  class="slds-card__body_inner">

            <lightning:messages/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" aura:id="accountLookup"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Department" aura:id="departmentText"/>

            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>

handleOnload : function(component, event, helper) {
    var parentId = component.get("v.parentId");

    // requires inputFields to have aura:id
    component.find("accountLookup").set("v.value", parentId);
    component.find("departmentText").set("v.value", "Accounting");
}
```

[image: recordEditForm]

```
As you can see above I am prepopulating AccountId, Department fields. There are other methods such as onSubmit onSuccess which can be used for further needs.
```